# cmd error from python install script?

Tags: python

I'm installing a py script and when installing im getting this error :

```
"build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\url/url-cpp/src\url.pyd.manifest : general error c1010070: Failed to load and parse the manifest. The system cannot find the file specified.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'mt.exe' failed with exit status 31"
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

I have tried the `ld_args.append('/MANIFEST')` adding to `dir>\Lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py`.

Did not work for me. Is there anything else I can do?